# Firebase AB Testing: rules for event tracking time for conversion

Tags: firebase, firebase-ab-testing

We are trying to use Firebase for our experiments and in the process there were several questions that I could not find answers to. Maybe someone can help me here.

Question one: the logic of the Activation event in the experiment. If the Activation Event happened before the start of the experiment (if we use an existing event), can it happen that the actions of such users get into the experiment?

The second question is: how much time can elapse between the Activation event and the event that we specified in Goal to count the conversion. In general, what are the rules for event tracking time for conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question one:
No, activation event must be done after experiment is activated. It has to do with how Remote Config works with A/B testing. For more info see this question: [Firebase Remote Config A/B testing shows no results after 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311141/firebase-remote-config-a-b-testing-shows-no-results-after-24-hours)

Question two:
I don't see it confirmed in documentation but I'm pretty sure there is no time limit for that. This is not the same as attribution, where you have attribution window, this is just calculating how many users who had that setup, did some action (which doesn't have to be conversion, btw).