# Firebase Remote Config A/B testing shows no results

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

We've configured remote config Firebase A/B testing and everything works fine. The UI changes and logs show a/b test is applied. Though, we're not getting any data in Firebase.

We've checked the following topics and these seem to be implemented correctly.

- [AB testing config applied but firebase console show 0 users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444991/ab-testing-config-applied-but-firebase-console-show-0-users)
- [Firebase Remote Config A/B testing shows no results after 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311141/firebase-remote-config-a-b-testing-shows-no-results-after-24-hours)

Our current code:

```
 val configSettings = FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(0)
                .setFetchTimeoutInSeconds(120)
                .build()
        remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings)
        remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnCanceledListener {
             ...
        }.addOnCompleteListener {
             ...
        }
```

Our activation event is trigged via GTM. Maybe we're missing something?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any solution for this?